# JS ROT 13 is working partially but not all the way through

Tags: javascript, function

I have no idea where my mistake is in this function. It is working for some strings but not for all. Could you maybe give me some advice. 
I want to accept a string and the function should return a string + 13 characters in the alphabet. If there is a number or special character just print it as it is 
So it works for `rot13("aaaabbbb55")` but it does not for `rot13("father4")`
Thanks for the help!

```
function rot13(message) {
  var ceasar = message.toLowerCase().split("");
  var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
  for (i = 0; i < ceasar.length; i++) {
    var letter = ""
    if (ceasar[i].match(/[a-z]/gi)) {
      letter = alpha.indexOf(ceasar[i])
      ceasar[i] = alpha[letter + 13]
    } else {
      continue
    };
  }
  return ceasar.join("")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `letter + 13`...what happens if `ceasar[i]` is `z`, for example? `else continue` is superfluous. The loop continues automatically.

Comment: Change `letter + 13` to `(letter + 13) % alpha.length` so it wraps around.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058968/js-rot-13-is-working-partially-but-not-all-the-way-through#comment104357434_59058968):

> Change `letter + 13` to `(letter + 13) % alpha.length` so it wraps around.

Basically, the problem with the line `ceasar[i] = alpha[letter + 13]` is that when a letter is after the middle point of the alphabet, `letter + 13` will result in an index that is out of bound. For instance, the letter `t`, in `father`, corresponds to the index 19 (0-based index). 19 + 13 = 32, which does not correspond to a letter in `alpha`.

Using the module operator with `(letter + 13) % alpha.length` will "wrap" 32 back to 6, which would be the letter `g`.